# LT spice simulation doesn't work. After a long time of waiting I see timestep too small error

Tags: ltspice

So I was trying to recreate this circuit, [image]
and only different thing are pins of that middle TL072 opamp. I have no clue how to do it properly so simulation would run.[image]
you can download project here: https://github.com/kszlk07/kue

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to apply power to these op-amps; a simulator doesn't recognize a dual op-amp: -

[image]

You apply power just as you have done for the un-circled op-amps except, you need to make the power supply polarity match the symbols on **ALL** the op-amp: -

[image]

I'm not saying there aren't other problems.

Some kind of three-band graphic equalizer?

Comment: I'm trying to recreate this effect: https://www.diyguitarpedals.com.au/shop/boms/Swedish%20Chainsaw.pdf
other segments are working fine expect tone stack segment